# Results about Hausdorff measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $$\mathcal{H}(A):=\lim_{\delta\to0}\mathcal{H}_{\delta}^s(A)$$ the Hausdorff measure.

Let $0\leq s<t<\infty.$ I want to show that if $\mathcal{H}^s(A)<\infty$, then $\mathcal{H}^t(A)=0$, and if $\mathcal{H}(A)^t>0$, then $\mathcal{H}^s(A)=\infty.$

How can I use the Hausdorff dimension in this problem?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you should use the Hausdorff dimension in this problem. The fact you stated is  used to *define* the Hausdorff dimension. And it follows from the inequality 
$$
\mathcal H^t(A) \le \delta^{t-s} \mathcal H^s(A)
$$
which is a direct consequence of the definition of $\mathcal H^t(A)$.

Comment: But what is delta?